# Descriptive Pinout for Cubieboard3/Cubietruck GPIO

Tags: python, arm, server, gpio

I've recently installed the [WiringCB-python](https://github.com/gootoomoon/WiringCB-python) library on my Cubietruck as I'd like to start using it's GPIO.

I can find **pinouts for the Cubietruck's GPIO** but I can't understand which pins are the ones that I can read inputs from or send outputs to.

I'd like to be able to use the functions:

```
wiringpi2.digitalRead(pin_number_here)
```

to read inputs, and

```
wiringpi2.digitalWrite(pin_number_here,1)
```

to write outputs and start my GPIO experimenting.

**Can anyone explain to me what the PG0-PG11, PB's, PI's and other pin numbers mean** on [this](http://docs.cubieboard.org/_media/products/a20_cubietruck/ct-pin%E8%84%9A%E5%9B%BE.png) pinout? I can see the VCC-3V, GND and VCC-5V as they're fairly descriptive, but I can't find a table anywhere which translates the others into plain english.

Cubietruck is an excellent platform and it's working well for me as an ownCloud server, but I'm having difficulty deciphering the documentation for the GPIO side of things.

Comment: The `PIN` is the pin number of the header installed on the board for making connections. The `DEF` is the Allwinner SoC pin name that is associated with that header pin.  For further explanation of each pin name use the **Allwinner A10 Datasheet**  (e.g. the section on "Pin Description").   Use the **Allwinner A10 User Manual** for details on accessing each PIO pin (e.g. the section on "Port Controller").

Answer (score 0):

I've followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGhfpfbnaeQ) to determine the port G pins, although you can probably figure out other pins as well.

- Cubietruck: WiringCB
- PG0: 53
- PG1: 58
- PG2: 57
- PG3: 56
- PG4: 59
- PG5: 60
- PG6: 61
- PG7: 62
- PG8: 63
- PG9: 64
- PG10: 65
- PG11: 66